# I have problems when mounting my USB drive in a nonstandard location

Tags: live-usb

My USB drive gets mounted under `/media/username`. I tried using umount to mount under `/media/usbdisk` instead. Well, theoretically it worked, but when I used MultiSystem Multiboot USB Creator it doesn’t recognize my USB drive under `/media`. I searched this entire site and didn’t find a solution. This issue also happened with the Sardu Multiboot USB Creator. And when I tried YUMI, it also did not recognize the drive. However, my OS does correctly recognise the USB drive under `/media/usbdisk`.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and my kernel version is 3.19.0-26. How do I solve this? I could find only partial solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may be confusing that bootable USB creators don’t recognize the USB drive when the OS is doing it properly. The simple solution is to use Gnome’s own disk utility. Use Startup Disk Creator and format your drive (clicking “erase disk” will do the job for you). Then you are good to go.

P.S.: I don’t recommend GParted 0.18 because it completely trashed my USB drive. It has problems with FAT32.